# Newton's Ring: interference problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, interference

Newton's ring apparatus consists of a Plano-spherical glass which rests on its vertex on top if a horizontal surface. Reflection-interference occurs along the air wedge, and is seen as a series of concentric rings from above. You may assume the radius of convergence is much larger than the thickness of the wedge.

Now, to the actual problem. 
When a liquid is introduced into the air between the glass and table, the radius of the tenth bright fring changes from $1.50$ cm to $1.31$ cm from the center of the pattern. Calculate the index of refraction of the liquid.

Comment: Your equation for the location of the bright ring is incorrect: see the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_rings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the equation from wikipedia, 
${ \Upsilon  }_{ N }={ \left[ \left( N-\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) \lambda R \right]  }^{ { 1 }/{ 2 } }$

Making a ratio using the information you provided, I get:
$\frac { 1.50 }{ 1.31 } =\frac { { \left[ \left( 10-\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) \lambda R \right]  }^{ { 1 }/{ 2 } } }{ { \left[ \left( 10-\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) \frac { \lambda  }{ n } R \right]  }^{ { 1 }/{ 2 } } } $

As you can see, the curvature of the lens and the light's wavelength cancels so you will be able to find the index of refraction.